# "Shall" versus "will" for the first person

Tags: word-choice

When I studied English, I was taught that *shall* is used to express the future tense for the first person (singular, or plural), and *will* is used for the same purpose in the other cases.

When I look for *shall* on the NOAD, I read the following sentence, in a note about the usage of *shall*:

> In practice, however, shall and will are today used more or less interchangeably in statements (although not in questions).

Does that mean *shall* and *will* are used with almost the same meaning?

Does *I shall return* have the same meaning of *I will return*?

Comment: I generally use `will` with I in formal/informal situation, whatever the case maybe, but I did not know in interrogative sentecne I should use `shall`. Let's see what our experts say!

Comment: @Mistu4u In questions _shall_ can have a different meaning. For example, "Shall we go?" is different from "Will we go?" The first question is making a suggestion, while the second one is asking if something is going to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NOAD is right. As ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ comments:

> **Will* is now the standard choice for expressing future plans and expectations, everywhere in the world. *Shall* is stylistically marked
>   with volitional meaning in legal and regulatory statements, and
>   expresses politeness in first person questions.

Comment: That seems the opposite of "used more or less interchangeably": _Will_ is used for a purpose, and _shall_ is used from a different purpose. At least, I understand _interchangeably_ as meaning that I could replace _will_ with _shall_ and the meaning would not change.

Answer (score 0):

What you were taught is still correct today, it is just commonly used differently. But that doesn't make it proper English!

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/shall-or-will