# Difference between will and shall

Tags: meaning, word-usage, modal-verbs

What is the difference between **will** and **shall** in modern spoken English?

For example I have the following sentences:

> He will arrive on Tuesday.
>
> He shall arrive on Tuesday.

Are there any rules specifying usage of *will* and *shall*?

**Reopen note:**

I looked at this question here:

- ["Shall" versus "will" for the first person](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2874/shall-versus-will-for-the-first-person)

But that question is about the use of the first person with *will* and *shall*. In addition one of the comments under here states that *will* and *shall* are NOT used in the same way in modern English. The linked-to question says they ARE. Which of these is correct and why?

Comment: "I will drown!  No one shall save me!  No, wait, I mean I *shall* drown, and...hey, where is everybody?"

Comment: The duplicate covers it pretty well.  Short answer: "will" is plan or intention, "shall" is generally imperative (must); but for first person, a more definitive statement than "will".

Comment: ... Do people actually use shall in this case anymore?

Comment: A Lord of the Rings analogy:  "You **will** not pass" would be a prediction of likely events.  "You **shall** not pass" means it ain't happening.

Comment: @Catija - In some fraternal ritual work, 'shall' is used to convey the meaning that one is directed to do something.

Comment: *Will* and *shall* are NOT used the same way in modern English at all. *Shall* is quite rare in declarative sentences in modern spoken English (although it is used occasionally).

Comment: @fixer1234 isn't any future statement a prediction? You can never be sure of what is going to happen in the future. I assume you meant that the likeliness of not passing is greater in "you shall not pass" than in "you will not pass" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main use of the auxiliary verbs **Shall** and **Will** is to form the **Simple Future**.  However these days, the use of Shall to form the Simple Future is becoming rare (especially in the US).

1. With modern English Grammar the Simple Future is usually formed with Will.
2. Shall is often used to make suggestions, offers or ask for advice (with questions using I and We):

   - Shall I carry your Bag? (Offer)
   - Shall I get you a cup of coffee?  (Offer)
   - Shall we go out tonight? (suggestion)
   - Shall we take a break? (suggestion)
   - Shall I call again on Thursday? (Seeking Advice)
   - What shall we do with this? (Seeking Advice)
3. Shall and Will are used to make **promises, commands or threats**:

   - There shall/will be no trespassing on this property. (Command)
   - You shall/will pay for this. (Threat)
   - You shall/will get your money back soon. (Promise)
4. In **American English** Shall is still commonly used in **Formal** or **Legal documents**.

   - You shall abide by the law. (Legal)

---

For more information the references are below:
[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/shall)
[Grammar-Monster.com](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/shall_will.htm)
[My English Pages](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-shall-will.php)

Answer (score 10):

Here's the differences between *shall* and *will* - they are interchangeable most of the time.

- *Shall* has a "fancy" or "formal" connotation to it.
- *Shall* can be used in questions to communicate that you want to take care of  or provide service to someone, whereas *will* cannot - i.e. it can be used in place of *may*.  For example, a waiter can say "Shall I take your order?" to ask for a customer's order, but *Will I take your order?" doesn't work.
- Shall cannot take place of *may* if *may* is being used to communicate a possibility (in contrast to something that we believe will 100% happen in the future).  "The car may stop working at any moment" is not the same as "The car shall stop working at any moment."
- When the subject is not a person, there is more likely to be an implication that the statement is really a request or a decree: *The sled shall slide down the hill* - someone wants the sled to do that as opposed to it happening due to circumstances.  This implication can exist with *will* but not by default.
- *Shall* appears in legal documents and contracts and therefore can have such an implication/connotation.

Comment: Yes, in spoken English at least, *shall* is mainly reserved for offers and appears mainly in interrogative sentences. It is quite rare in declarative sentences where it does have a similar meaning to *will*.

Comment: @Araucaria As I added in my answer, there are more exceptions to using one over the other.

Answer (score 7):

On the web and in books different sources tell us different information. However, I have analyzed most of that information and I believe the interjections are the true information. So:

1. In English the outdated rule is that **shall** is used with first person pronouns (i.e. I and we) to form the future tense, while **will** is used with second and third person forms (i.e. you, he, she, it, they).
2. When it comes to expressing a strong determination to do something (to express a strong feeling that something must definitely happen, or that someone must do something as a duty), traditional grammar dictates that in this case **will** is used with the first person, and **shall** with the second and third. This mainly applies to American English and mostly British English.
3. Some varieties of English, including Scottish and Irish English, tend to use **will** instead of **shall** when talking about the future, no matter if it’s with the first, second, or third person pronoun.
4. In practice, the two words are mostly used interchangeably, and this is now an acceptable part of standard British and American English; however, the word **shall** is now seldom used in any normal context in American English.
5. In spoken English, **shall** and **will** are usually contracted to *’ll*, especially after subject pronouns (I, we, you, they, she, he, it) and therefore there’s no need to worry too much about the distinction when referring to the future.
6. We use **shall** in questions to make suggestions or offers, or to ask for advice rather than to refer to future time.

- ***Shall** we have coffee?* (not **will**)
- ***Shall** I open the window?* (not **will**)

7. **Shall** is most often used in formal written English especially when referring to a legal duty or formal instruction.

- *This document states that she **shall** not keep the child to herself.*

8. ***Rule:*** **Will**, but never **shall**, is used to ask or order someone to do something.

- ***Will** you visit Ann once you're in London?* (never **shall**)
- ***Will** you shut up, please!* (never **shall**)

9. The short form of **shall not** - shan't is very rare in American English and rare in British English.
10. When talking about the future, **will** is dominant and **shall** seems to have fallen into disuse (especially in American English). **Shall** occurs mainly in questions expressing suggestions or seeking agreement, and in legal usage.
11. When used with second and third person pronouns **shall** expresses a command. Both **shall** and **will** are sometimes used to make a promise or to express a threat.

- *You **shall** go to bed now!*
- *He **shall**/**will** get what he wants if he does what I told him to do.*
- *You **shall**/**will** pay for this!*

12. When we express willingness we use **will**.

- *'I'm sorry, he's talking on the phone right now.','Alright, I **will** wait.'*

The sources of all this information are mainly these:

1. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://web.archive.org/web/20220824090357/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/shall-or-will)
2. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-will-and-shall)
3. [Daily Writing Tips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-difference-between-will-and-shall/)
4. [Learn English British Council](https://web.archive.org/web/20181121163605/http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org:80/en/category/grammar/grammar-will-or-shall)
5. [Difference Between](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/grammar-language/difference-between-shall-and-will-in-english-grammar/)
6. [English Grammar](https://www.englishgrammar.org/uses-of-shall-and-will/)
7. [Education First](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/)
8. [Business Dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20200927103419/http://www.businessdictionary.com/article/959/shall-vs-will-d1113/)
9. [BBC Learning English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page28.shtml)
10. [Woodward English](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507035154/https://www.grammar.cl/english/shall.htm)
11. [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shall)
12. [Oxford Dictionary Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20170709152137/http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/09/will-versus-shall/)

Comment: Your post is self-contradictory, old bean ... And some of it is misleading. For example, you write "*Some varieties of English, including Scottish and Irish English, tend to use will instead of shall when talking about the future, no matter if it’s with the first, second, or third person pronoun.*" I don't know a variety of English that that ***isn't*** true for!!! It's true for *all* modern English. Also I don't think the 'traditional' (read nineteenth century prescriptive) rule is of any use whatsoever to readers here, or learners anywhere.

Comment: @Araucaria Could you argue with the sources? Wherever I read the sources admit that mostly English tends to use will instead of shall for first person in modern English, but not always. Traditional has to be understood. Even while modern English has changed traditional rules still exist and should be known by learners. I myself am a learner and I need to know this.

Comment: That's not helpful for learners at all. Because it doesn't work!!!!! :D Don't teach rules that don't work. A rule that doesn't work is not a rule!

Comment: @Araucaria Excuse me but what rules don't work?

Comment: Your number one.

Comment: @Araucaria It is a traditional rule indeed and grammar books say so too. What bothers you about it?

Comment: What bothers me about it? IT ISN'T A RULE OF ENGLISH. As the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002) says: "*It is quite clear [...] that this rule is not valid*" (p.195)

Comment: They continue ... "[W]e must allow *will* as well as *shall* for the 1ST person - and modern usage manuals recognise this. *Will* (including the contracted variant *'ll*) is in fact very much more common, and indeed in AmE *shall* is quite rare. "

Comment: @Araucaria That's exactly why I kept the word traditional. I agree that modern grammar says different and of course I agree with Cambridge.

Comment: *Traditional* is dubious. It's better to say that the rule is outdated, old-fashioned, or anything that makes it clearer that the rule is incorrect in Present-Day English. (cc @Araucaria)

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you need to know about *will* and *shall* in English.

(1) *Will* is far more frequent in English than *shall*. In American English *shall* is very rare.

(2) *Will* and *shall* are both used to describe the future in general:

- I will be there at around 9 am.
- I shall be there at around 9 am.

However, speakers are far more likely to use *will* than *shall* here. In addition *shall* can sound too formal or haughty in the wrong situation.

(3) We use *shall* for offers and suggestions. We can't use *will* for this. We always use a question form:

- Shall I open the window?
- Shall we go to the cinema?

In the first example, I am offering to open the window. In the second example, I am suggesting that we go to the cinema. In both examples I want the listener to make the decision. This use of *shall* is less common in American English.

**Advice for learners**

Use *will*, not *shall*, for talking about the future in general. Use *shall* for offers and suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

My English teacher used to say "I and we 'shall' and everybody else 'will'", but this was many years ago and probably doesn't reflect modern English usage.

Comment: It's the same in modern English but there is a lot more to the usages of shall and will.

Comment: If you were to edit out the 'probably' you might be in danger of getting a 500 point bounty!!!

Answer (score 2):

The *OED* has 29 separate primary senses for ["shall, *v.*"](https://www.oed.com/start;jsessionid=864B679C823D1CF08F158EF398F6B35B?authRejection=true&url=%252Fview%252FEntry%252F177350), and 52 for ["will, *v.¹*"](https://www.oed.com/start;jsessionid=618157BCC69FF87D1740FE8E05C251DC?authRejection=true&url=%252Fview%252FEntry%252F229051).

[The short version is that **will** (indefinite future), **going to** (near future), and **about to** (immediate future) are all preferred to **shall** in modern spoken English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=about%20to%20do,going%20to%20do,will%20do,shall%20do&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=16&smoothing=3) with a very few exceptions.

- **On tests** and in other very formal situations, [it's standard in British English to prefer *shall* over *will* for first-person pronouns. *I shall*..., *We shall*..., *Everyone else will...*](https://web.archive.org/web/20220824090357/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/shall-or-will) Particularly, that usage is an important feature of some tests of English as a foreign language. [The only exception is in situations of *volition*](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=tuCdBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT27), where *I will* is being used as equivalent as *I choose to*... (That is, *I exercise my will*...) The resistance to contractions on tests usually precludes eliding the difference between the two by just using *'ll* for both.
- *Shall* has become [so uncommon in other English dialects](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=ZuUc6JtABmkC&pg=PA91) that their speakers usually only associate it with [**Shakespeare**](https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/Library/facsimile/overview/book/F1.html) and the [**King James Bible**](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1611-Bible/). [Like *thou*, it's used without regard to proper syntax to imitate or reference early modern English](https://web.archive.org/web/20170217021151/https://www.londonbridgerenfaire.com/olde-english-language-guide.html).

Proper use of *shall* is based on [its original sense of obligation or necessity](https://www.oed.com/start;jsessionid=864B679C823D1CF08F158EF398F6B35B?authRejection=true&url=%252Fview%252FEntry%252F177350), as opposed to *will's* [bare statement of desire or fact regarding the future](https://www.oed.com/start;jsessionid=618157BCC69FF87D1740FE8E05C251DC?authRejection=true&url=%252Fview%252FEntry%252F229051). This is why its use became restricted to the first person: you can make binding promises as to your or your group's own future actions, but cannot properly do so on behalf of others who are outside your control.

Using *shall* for the second or third person is tantamount to giving orders ("You are obliged to...") and, appropriately, the context where it sees use is in **law** and **legal documents** (contracts, wills, prenuptial agreements, &c.). *Will* and the other expressions have made inroads there as well but *shall* remains relatively common in most jurisdictions with precisely the divine and obligatory nature implied by the *Thou shalts...* and *Thou shalt nots...* of the Ten Commandments. NASA's lawyers even use it for a particular form of imperative in their contracts and requirement specs ["to dictate the provision of a functional capability"](https://web.archive.org/web/20071211035725/http://satc.gsfc.nasa.gov/support/STC_APR97/write/writert.html).

([The idea that certain future events take *shall* in the 2nd- and 3rd-person](https://web.archive.org/web/20220824090357/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/shall-or-will) comes from misunderstanding this feature of the word: *will* is just as certain but *shall* connotes a duty to make efforts to ensure its certainty.)

[The one redoubt of *shall* in daily life is in **asking questions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will). Because of the vanilla sometime-in-the-indefinite-future nature of *will*, it is not usually used to make requests or ask about the near future. *Will we dance?* is a largely impersonal question about a future event. *Will I take your order?* is a question that only waiters themselves can answer for certain. *Shall I take your order?* is a polite request to know if now is a good time for that certain action and *Shall we dance?* is spoken while rising from a chair and extending a hand. *Shall we say...* is particularly common, though less so than its effective synonym *Let's say...* Less often, similar questions can also be asked in the 2nd person—*Shall you come?*—and essentially wonder whether the listener agrees to place themselves under the obligation to perform the action (*I shall come* being equivalent to, *Yes, I promise that I will come*).

Comment: I feel you're  misunderstanding (or  inadvertantly misconstruing) the Oxford entry. It is not "standard" (as in common or normal) in British English to use *will* and *shall* in different ways according to different grammatical persons. Rather that used to be a prescriptive grammar 'rule' promoted by nineteenth century pedants and early twentieth century usage guides. It is virtually entirely ignored in modern English -even in formal English- and many, if not most, speakers are entirely unaware of it. Do you have any evidence for your test assertion. Anecdotally, I don't find it convincing ...

Comment: ... I've been teaching for quite a while now, (and studying, of course). I've never seen or heard of any modern test that uses that prescriptive rule. I like the part of your post where you say "The short version is that will (indefinite future), going to (near future), and about to (immediate future) are all preferred to shall in modern spoken English with a very few exceptions." <-- to which I don't think British English is *that* much of an exception.

Comment: @Araucaria With respect, I don't think my reading comp is the one suffering here. Both the Oxford entry and my post make it very clear that every variety of English mostly doesn't bother with *shall* at all. On the other hand, as stated, the Oxford cite very clearly supports that extremely formal situations in British English *do* make note of the distinction.

Comment: As far as tests, it certainly isn't part of the American TOEFL but Oxford and the British sources continue to mention it. I'll defer to a cite that it's a nonissue [but it still features in IELTS material](http://www.ielts-practice.org/difference-between-will-and-shall/) and is certainly a feature of the Oxford and other British test materials used in the PRC and on the native Chinese *Gaokao*, the college entrance examination that essentially sets the career trajectories of the leadership of the next superpower.

Comment: In any case, *for* the British grader who *does* have a hair up his whatsit over the issue, this is *how* it's supposed to work. As already mentioned, yes, in most informal situations the only oddity would be using *shall* in the first place. The reply is most likely to be something along the lines of a faux-obsequious "What was that, m'lud?"

Comment: I agree with your last comments. Re IELTS, you won't find it in any of the official Cambridge IELTS materials and IELTS examiners don't recognise it (but will quite happily downgrade a candidate for writing inappropriate pompous twaddle by using *shall* where *will* would be more natural).

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries. [Ah, but we should never use dictionaries for grammar advice!](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635) ;)