# When I must use `shall` and when I must use `will`?

Tags: will-shall

I know, `shall` we use only with `I` and `We`.
Is it right?
But can I use `will` with `I` and `We`?
Is it true in the USA `shall` use rarely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between will and shall](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124164/difference-between-will-and-shall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this seems to be a duplicate, I shall try to explain the difference between the use of shall and will.

As far as the first person is considered there is no difference in  modern English with  regard  to  statements whether it is American or the British English.

> **I shall/ will go** is used to talk about colourless future.

you will do it( prediction)

you / he shall do it ( obligation)

Shall I open the door?( seeking permission)

You can not say  **Will I open the door?**( do I have the ability to open the door)

**Shall we go for a walk?**( suggestion) you should not use **will** here.

Here is a link which may help you.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-will-and-shall

Comment: If you check the constructions you outlaw (**will I open** and **will we go**) on Google Books Ngram Viewer, you will find that they are in common usage and have been for hundreds of years. I suggest to you that while they may not fit old grammar school rules, they are both valid and idiomatic.

Comment: Ronald Sole. You can find the usage In Raymond Murphy's grammar.They are not wrong but  have  a different  meaning

Comment: While I prefer the usages that you commend, I suggest that they are outdated as rules and that you certainly can say them. Google Books Ngram Viewer shows that **will I open** and **shall I open** have been used in equal measure since the mid 18th century. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shall+I+open%2Cwill+I+open&year_

Comment: I would like to whether Raymond Murphy and Michael Swan  are  descriptive, modern grammarians or  prescriptive  and traditional gramarians?